# Glassfish 4 deployment order for auto deploying war-files

Tags: java, deployment, war, glassfish-4

My applications consists of set of war-files. One of components has a scheduled task wcich depends on some other war. So I want to specify deployment order of these components. I deploy my application by placing all the wars in glassfish autodeploy folder in some remote production servers, so I can't use domain.xml to configure deployment order. And I want to specify war-file deployment order in descriptor, something like glassfish-web.xml. But I can't find that parameter in any of them. Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know you can not specify a deployment order for multiple war files in the autodeploy directory.

The reason is that the glassfish [AutoDeployDirectoryScanner](https://github.com/javaee/glassfish/blob/4.1.2/nucleus/deployment/autodeploy/src/main/java/org/glassfish/deployment/autodeploy/AutoDeployDirectoryScanner.java) scans the directory via [File.listfiles()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) and as the javadoc of File states:

> There is no guarantee that the name strings in the resulting array will appear in any specific order

The glassfish autodeployer creates an empty file with **.war_deployed** suffix.

*Example:* For *yourfile.war* the autodeployer creates a *yourfile.war_deployed* file. The original war file will still be in the directory.

*My suggestion:*

You can check for the existence of a *.war_deployed*  file and trigger the copy process of the next war file.

You migth run a script/cronjob which copies the files in the desired order one after one to the autodeploy directory if the previous war was deployed succesfully.